# Apache Benchmark HTTPS failing

Tags: apache, ssl, benchmarking

I'm using Apache 2.4.2 in Ubuntu virtual machine.
I use this to load test, sending request to some HTTPS url.
Number of failed request is zero. But none of my request can truly be processed (looked up in database already).
With the same url, invoke it through the browser is ok (database updated).
So it was purely the issue of Apache Benchmark.
Here's my Apache Benchmark command:

```
# ab -n 100 -c 10 -k -f ALL -g "/home/administrator/Desktop/g.txt" -e "home/administrator/Desktop/e.txt" "https://mysecuredurl.com/MyWCF.svc/POX/MyMethod?arg=something"
```

When I omit -k argument, SSL connection shown out clearly that they're the issue:

**SSL read failed - closing connection**

```
Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:      845  851   4.0    852     857
Processing:   218  232  20.4    229     286
Waiting:      218  232  20.4    229     286
Total:       1068 1083  19.6   1076    1131
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue, in order that I can utilize Apache Benchmark for my load test with HTTPS, passing-by SSL issue ?
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

When I used ab with a https URL, it threw me out with this message
**SSL not compiled in; no https support**

It worked fine using **abs**

Comment: I was afraid of crazy configurations and heavy Windows-rebuilding things... but it's only about adding a "s" to "ab"! Thanks a lot ☺

Comment: There is no `abs` in Ubuntu apache2-utils package

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems like this is a known bug

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49382

There is a patch there but no clear instruction on how to apply it. You may want to take a look at http://jungels.net/articles/diff-patch-ten-minutes.html as a starter.