# I found a issue that when I'm using apache benchmark(ab) with http

Tags: apache, ssl, https

I found a issue that when I'm using apache benchmark(ab) with http,it is working fine but when I'm running ab with HTTPS , I'm getting error "benchmarking : SSL read failed - closing connection". Any ideas how could it be resolved

Comment: looks like the server does not do HTTPS. Can you open the page in a browser? Does `curl` or `wget` work?

Comment: or maybe it's this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928855/apache-benchmark-https-uncapable?rq=1

Comment: using wget i'm getting this error " Proxy tunneling failed: Internal Server ErrorUnable to establish SSL connection."

Answer (score 13):

Try [Siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/), it's similar to ab, but it can handle https with not trusted certificates.

With Siege you can create a file with URLs you want to test (`-f` option), the `-c` tells how many users (concurrency) and `-t` how much time (e.g.: `1M` one minute, `2H` two ours)

```
siege -c 10 -t 1m -f file.txt
```

If you are using Debian, you can do a `apt-get install siege`

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be bug that occurs on some servers:

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49382

Answer (score 1):

This also happens if you are using an intermediate certificate authority (StartSSL free tier) that is not trusted by the client and misconfigured your SSL certificate.

You need to add the intermediate CA's certificate to your webserver's SSL certificate so that it looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
..YOUR CERT......
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
..INTERMEDIATE CA CERT......
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the certificate in the machine from where you perform the request.